# url encoding okhttp3 android remove %20

Tags: android, api, replace, okhttp

Hi i created a GET call using Okhttp3 library in Android for a cURL call like this:

```
  curl -X GET "http://1.1.1.1:8080/api/v1/login" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 123456"
```

in this way using OkHttp3 library in Android

```
final String url = BuildConfig.BASE_AUTH_URL + "/login" + "/" + token;

Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(url)
              .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
              .get()
              .build();
...
```

but in the log that i printed in the logcat, the request fails (500 Internal Server Error) because the url has an "%20" as a "space" after the word "Bearer"

```
 Request{method=GET, url=http://1.1.1.1:8080/login/Bearer%20123456
```

and the error was `<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Server Error</body></html>`

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Error< of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I tried to use *token.replace("%20", " ")* method or  *URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8")* and others, but none works.

Can someone please help me to encode in the right way without the "%20" chatacter in the url?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between what you're attempting using curl, and what you're doing using the OkHttp library.

In curl you're adding two headers. In OkHttp you added one header and appended the token to the url instead of adding it to the header.

Your code should look something like this: (Assuming `token = "Bearer 123456"`)

```
final String url = BuildConfig.BASE_AUTH_URL + "/login"; // removed token from here

Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(url)
              .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
              .addHeader("Authorization", token) // Auth header added here
              .get()
              .build();
...
```